# spark constructs 1-1, 1-M relationships?

Tags: apache-spark

spark has many constructs:

- application
- driver
- executor
- worker node
- partition
- dataframe/rdd
- shuffle
- job
- stage
- task
- input file
- output file
- core

is there any diagram showing the relationships between them?

ie

each worker node can have 0-many executors. At least 1 worker should have at least 1 executor. But some workers might have no executors

partition to task is 1 to many

executor to core is 1 to many
..etc

Answer (score 0):

This explains the Spark execution model in detail. https://mapr.com/blog/how-spark-runs-your-applications/

**Execution model**

[image]

**How shuffles work**

[image]

https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/